# Php array drops records after exactly 1001 records

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem. We have PHP 4 loaded onto a server and after a upgrade of PHP seems to drop every record after 1001 in a multi array that is passed through to a csv file. the ,multi array has 8000 records and all the records is populated from 1 to 1001 after that it gives null and zero values. Any help?

Comment: upgrade probably changed the ini values for script timeouts and such....

Comment: does any error, notice or warnings are fired up (error_reporting is on)?

Comment: In addition to a code sample, also a CSV sample please.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? Please mark it as the answer then?

Answer (score 2):

Does your PHP use Suhosin? Check phpinfo(); Had a problem once with Suhosin silently dropping items in arrays in POST beyond 1000. No error in any log. Just dropped. Seems similar to your problem.

suhosin.post.max_vars=10000

suhosin.request.max_vars=10000

or perhaps

max_input_vars = 10000

Comment: max_input_vars fixed me when I encountered this